# How do I add buttons to an activity class with a ListView in Eclipse (Android)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, button

I currently have an app that shows a list of campfire songs and when clicked on, they open up another activity. The next activity that is opened looks how I want it to, but the buttons that I have specified in the XML haven't been linked up in the code and I don't know where they fit in, or if what I have is right.

Here is my Java file for Menu.java:

```
package com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[] = {"......"};

    String items[] = {"......"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        final ImageButton settings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);
        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, Settings.class);
                Menu.this.startActivity(settingsIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        final ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String song_activity = classes[position];
        try{
        Class<?> ourClass = Class.forName("com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs." + song_activity);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the XML file for my menu:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SelectSong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/SelectSong"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ic_launcher"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" >

    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_launcher"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_button_selected"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:src="@drawable/exit_button_selected"
        android:contentDescription="@string/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat errors:

```
12-19 16:39:13.143: E/Trace(809): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-19 16:39:13.973: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 9% free 7344K/8003K, paused 67ms, total 69ms
12-19 16:39:14.003: I/dalvikvm-heap(809): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.133MB for 1536016-byte allocation
12-19 16:39:14.173: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 8% free 8842K/9543K, paused 85ms+8ms, total 166ms
12-19 16:39:14.353: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 8842K/9543K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
12-19 16:39:14.374: I/dalvikvm-heap(809): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.286MB for 1209856-byte allocation
12-19 16:39:14.533: D/dalvikvm(809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 10024K/10759K, paused 78ms+18ms, total 162ms
12-19 16:39:14.913: D/gralloc_goldfish(809): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-19 16:39:20.065: D/AndroidRuntime(809): Shutting down VM
12-19 16:39:20.065: W/dalvikvm(809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs/com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at com.lmarshall1995.scoutsongs.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:43)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-19 16:39:20.103: E/AndroidRuntime(809):  ... 11 more
12-19 16:39:23.223: I/Process(809): Sending signal. PID: 809 SIG: 9
```

There are two buttons. One for Settings, which I would like to open the Settings.java class activity, and the other to exit the app by closing the current activity. I currently get an error after my splash screen, Logcat shown above.

Any suggestions as to how to change anything in any of these codes? Is there anything that needs adding in? Where to put the code/s?

Thanks,
From
Laurence =]

Comment: The code you have so far looks right. Where do you have that code now? It can go in `onCreate()` of the `Activity` whose `layout` has those `Button`s.

Comment: After `setContentView()`.

Comment: I would agree with you too @Nizam but when I do that, I get "Unfortunately, Scout Campfire Songs has stopped." in the emulator.

Comment: Then you need to post the logcat from the crash and show exactly where you have this code.

Comment: 2 possible reasons. 1)menu.xml does not contain 2 buttons with specific id's. Or 2)The list view inside menu.xml have a wrong id.

Comment: @Nizam both of these are correct in the XML and Java... :-/

Comment: @LaurenceMarshall you need to post the logcat from the crash and more of the code where your `Button`s are so we have a better idea of what's going on. The logcat will tell us exactly what and where the exception is. There could be multiple reasons it isn't working.

Comment: Then we need more as @codeMagic said. Post Logcat. You are familiar with DDMS->Logcat, aren't you?

Comment: @Nizam Yes, I've updated the question above with the information requested.

Comment: Don't worry. I put "back" instead of "exit":
findViewById(R.id.exit_button);

Comment: So the problem solved?

Comment: @Nizam Yes, don't worry. Thank you all for your help.